# use case for uuid in database

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say for example I have a table called `test` and the data is like that:

```
id name
1  John
2  Jay
3  Maria
```

Let's suppose this `test` gets updated and now the `ids` the names are for some reason allocated to different `id` , consider the `name` column as a unique column, it's just not the pprimary key of `test` but unique.

Next time I query `test` it may look like that:

```
   id name
    10  John
    12  Jay
    13  Maria
```

So in that case the `id` changed but the `name` is consistent can be traced back to the previous state of the `test` table. I believe this is bad practice to change `id` like that, but I don't have control over this table and this is how some folks handle right now the data. I would like to know if this is a good case for using `uuid` ? I'm not familiar with the concept of `uuid`, and how it's best to create something consistent as uniquely identifiable and also fast on search when I want to handle the data changes in this table. I would like to import this table on my end but create a key that is fast and that will not change during data imports.

Comment: How would a UUID solve the problem? If the primary keys are being changed then what does it matter if you use data type X or data type Y if you can never guarantee consistency of the values for those data types?

Comment: how about uuid on the `name` column ? is that viable ? that is unique and never changes

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the problem you're trying to solve isn't clear.

Problem 1: The id column keeps getting updated. This seems weird so getting to the root of why that is happening seems like the real issue to resolve.

Problem 2: Uniquely identifying rows. You would like to use the id column or a new uuid column to uniquely identify but you've already said you can uniquely identify rows with the name column so what problem are you trying to solve here.

Problem 3: Performance. You're going to get best performance using an indexed integer (preferably primary key) column. Most likely id in this case. uuid won't help with performance.

Problem 4: Data changing on imports. This is likely due to auto increments or initial values set differently in DDL. You need to get a better understanding of what exactly is going wrong with your import.

Problem 5: If you don't have control over the values of the id column how would you be able to add your own uuid?

uuid is just a way of creating a unique value.

Oracle has a function to create uuid random_uuid().

Comment: problem 1 concerns another team, I don't want to really discuss why they design the database that way. Anyways they would not change anyway and if they did it would take too much time.
problem 2 yes it's true but I want something more performant than a column with data type as `varchar2` , numerical index works better but i cannot use them. I want something that maps to `name` column consistently across different imports and yet is performant.
uuid is less performant than an index integer ? could you maybe explain why ? 
problem 5 i want to set a uuid to `name` not to `id`

Comment: A uuid is effectively a long varchar2. Oracle is generally impressive at cutting edge features so maybe they have some performance edges on uuid but there is no getting away from how difficult that must be to index. What comes after 1? Easy 2. What comes after afa2152e-b07e-41a5-9c30-8073922e57d8? Harder for an index to sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY-problem.

You have data in your table with a unique key in a given data type and when it gets reloaded then the unique key is being regenerated so that all the data gets given new unique values.

The data type you use does not matter; the issue is with the process of reloading the data and regenerating the unique keys. If you use a different data type and the unique keys are still regenerated then you have exactly the same problem.

Fix that problem first.

Comment: but apparently I can use `name` as unique key because that doesn't change when the data is reloaded and it's unique. However using name is not very performant because the data type is `varchar2` . I think a numerical index servers as a better purpose for a unique key but unfortunately that cannot be used. I was wondering the uuid would serve a better purpose. is it possible to create a uuid from the `name` column ? would that be a good strategy ? thanks

Comment: @moth A person's name is not unique; multiple people can have identical names. If your application does restrict to unique names then you can use that. UUIDs are random, they are not hashes of another value such as the name. I'm not sure why you are fixated on UUIDs and trying to create them over using an identity column or a unique string but whichever one you chose is a business decision and there is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: my real data this is not a person's name, it's the name of the server and the database has an unique constraint in that column. thanks for letting me know `uuid` are random and not hashes . I was told by someone today that they were hashes so I came here to ask for help

Comment: @moth it depends on the UUID version [summary here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) but for UUID versions 1, 2 and 4 they are not hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the reasons for this question and does it make sense or not. If I got it right it is about generation of a unique key from NAME which is unique itself.
If that is the case then you could create your on function to do the job:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NAME_2_ID(p_name VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS 
BEGIN
--
  Declare
    mRet        Number(16);
    mAlpha  VarChar2(64);
    mWrk        Number(16) := 0;
    mANum   VarChar2(4000) := '';
--
  Begin
    IF p_name Is Null Then
      mRet := 0;
      GOTO End_It;
    END IF;
--
    mAlpha := ' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'',.!?"()[]{}';
-- ---------------- Replacing  Alpha To Numeric -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    For i In 1 .. Length(p_name) Loop
        mANum := mANum || SubStr(p_name, i, 1) || To_Char(InStr(mAlpha, Upper(SubStr(p_name, i, 1)))) || '~';
        mWrk := mWrk + InStr(mAlpha, Upper(SubStr(p_name, i, 1)));
    End Loop;
    mRet := mWrk * Length(mANum);
<<End_It>>
    RETURN(mRet);
  End;
END NAME_2_ID;
```

As your ID column in TEST table is changing like in sample data:

```sql
WITH
    test_1 AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'John'  "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'Jay'   "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'Maria' "A_NAME" From Dual 
        ),
    test_2 AS
        (
            Select 10 "ID", 'John'  "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 12 "ID", 'Jay'   "A_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 13 "ID", 'Maria' "A_NAME" From Dual 
        )
```

... you can get the same ID_2 whenever you query the table (if name didn't
change) ...

```sql
Select 
    ID,
    A_NAME,
    NAME_2_ID(A_NAME) "ID_2"
From
    test_1
/*
        ID A_NAME       ID_2
---------- ------ ----------
         1 John          765 
         2 Jay           429 
         3 Maria         846
*/

--  -------------------------
... ... ...
  From 
     test_2

/*
        ID A_NAME       ID_2
---------- ------ ----------
        10 John          765 
        12 Jay           429 
        13 Maria         846
*/
```